# XOR Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, logic

Is there a way to put a condition that return true only if one of the two component return true?

```
BOOL var1
BOOL var2
```

something shorter than `if((var1 && !var2) || (!var1 && var2))`

Thank you

Comment: you can use this if(var1 ^ var2)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As Objective-C is a superset of C, you simply use the XOR operator from C, which is `^`.

Comment: That's the bitwise XOR, if you want a logical XOR, simply use `!=`.

Comment: Neither solution will work all the time. A BOOL can be any integer. Both will fail if both values are non-zero, but unequal. The most robust option is probably to write it out in full, like the original question.

Comment: @DrewMcCormack, to avoid this problem you can convert any type to real `BOOL` using two exclamation marks. `!!var1 != !!var2`

Answer (score 44):

XOR

```
if(!!var1 != !!var2)
{
   NSLog(@"XOR condition");
}
```

Exclamation marks convert vars to BOOL (real conversion, not casting)
So this solution works even if your variables are not BOOL.

```
!!(0|nil) ≡ 0  
!!(any other number|object) ≡ 1
```

This is useful in cases when you want to be sure that only one of vars is nonnil.

Comment: short, elegant, easy and simple

Comment: By default BOOL variable is NO. In this condition, i think it is fail.  Check it

Comment: I like this one btw but the carrot may be more academic thank for the answer

Comment: @Prasad G, By default bool variables are No. what the effect of that. xor condition TRUE,TRUE and False, false both condition gives False and True,False and False,TRUE gives True result. so where is the problem in above condition.

Comment: @Ishu: Yes. You are right but when bool variables are default it shows  XOR condition. whenever we assign NO to variables, there is no problem

Comment: @prasadG ,  BOOL a,b;
    
    if(a!=b)
    {
        NSLog(@"XOR");
    } //this code also not give me the wrong answer for default values

Comment: @Ishu: I have same problem. I don't know what happened to me.

Comment: You should be vigilant. Hold in mind, that if `var1 = string.length` or `var2 = mask | BitMaskConstant` it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You could add more **clearness** to the code that Ishu suggests by doing this:

```
#define XOR !=
```

and then you just write:

```
if (var1 XOR var2) {

    ...
}
```

---

truth table output: 
[T XOR T => F; T != T => F], 
[T XOR F => T; T != F => T], 
[F XOR T => T; F != T => T] and 
[F XOR F => F; F != F => F]

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yes it is, because it results in the same truth table: [T XOR T => F; T != T => F], [T XOR F => T; T != F => T], [F XOR T => T; F != T => T] and [F XOR F => F; F != F => F].

Comment: Woah you're right. I actually feel very foolish for not realizing this! Thank you for teaching me

Answer (score 2):

A macro could be an option. It will keep the same behaviour, but now in a more readable way.

`#define XOR(x,y) (((x) && !(y)) || (!(x) && (y)))`

```
if(XOR(var1, var2) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `(int)var1 ^ (int)var2`
YES and NO are actually defined as following:

```
#define YES (BOOL)1
#define NO  (BOOL)0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((!var1)==var2) 
{
        NSLog(@"Yes");
}
```